# Issue on dojo onlick event on html button

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I am a new kid with dojo, I got weird issue which I take lots of time and have not yet found out, assume I have 4 buttons:

```
<button id="btnMoveFirst" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" iconclass="plusIcon">
    &lt; &lt;</button>
<button id="btnMovePrev" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" iconclass="plusIcon">
    &lt;</button>
<button id="btnMoveNext" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" iconclass="plusIcon">
    &gt;</button>
<button id="btnMoveLast" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" iconclass="plusIcon">
    &gt; &gt;</button>
```

And use dojo with event *onclick* as below:

```
dojo.connect(dijit.registry.byId('btnMoveFirst'), "onclick",  function(evt){
    alert('test1');
});

dojo.connect(dijit.registry.byId('btnMovePrev'), "onclick",  function(evt){
     alert('test2');
});

dojo.connect(dijit.registry.byId('btnMoveNext'), "onclick",  function(evt){
     alert('test3');
});

dojo.connect(dijit.registry.byId('btnMoveLast'), "onclick",  function(evt){
     alert('test4');
});
```

But when I click any one of 4 buttons, or even any button in form, I got 4 alerts instead of only correct one.

Does anyone know this?

Comment: It is `onClick`, because it's not DOMEvent. What you do is telling Dojo to call your anonymous function after method `onclick` was invoked on your Dijit of choice. It is _Aspect Oriented Programming_ and there are more straightforward ways to register event listeners in the latest Dojo 1.7 & 1.8. I highly recommend to go with 1.8.1, if you can choose.

Comment: @phusick: thanks for your comment, please could you give me the link which show the different approach in dojo 1.8, I am using 1.8

Comment: In this particular case I meant [dojo/on](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/on.html) and [dojo/Evented](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/Evented.html). So you code will be like `registry.byId("btnMoveFirst").on("click", function(event) {});`.

Comment: @phusick: I have change from 'onclick' to 'onClick', I does not work at all, alerts did not pop up

Comment: I would say, it is because it's `dijit.byId("xxx")`, but wait a moment I will send you a working example in jsFiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/355MT/ - here is the recommended way to write your code in Dojo 1.8.

Comment: [Modern Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/modern_dojo/) is probably the best resource to start with: "If you find yourself typing `dojo.*` or `dijit.*` or `dojox.*`, something isn't right."

Comment: Not sure what you mean, click the link and it runs. To see `console.log()` output you need to open DevTools in Chrome (press F12) or Firebug in Firefox and select _console_ tab. It's also possible jsFiddle does not work for you, as it did not for me when I was in Asia (probably DNS resolving), therefore I will put the code in the answer below.

Comment: @phusick: I see it works on jsFiddler, but I cannot apply on my case. anyway thanks you for your help. Could you post an answer than I will mark it

Comment: Well, I added examples with `dojo.connect`, because modern Dojo or not, I am 100% sure one needs to use `onClick` when connecting dijits and `onclick` when connecting to DOM nodes with `dojo.connect`.

Comment: Another reason might be, that buttons are not instantiated (by parser) in the moment of invoking `dojo.connect`, which is why I used `dojo/ready` in the example code. There is also `dojo.ready()` from previous versions, if you prefer that.

Comment: @phusick: why you use dijit.byId not registry.byId?

Comment: I used it only with `dojo.connect` to make the entire connect written in legacy code, otherwise I do not use it at all. `registry.byId` works the same way I just did not want to mix legacy and contemporary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for *I got 4 alerts instead of only correct one* is the combination of:

- buttons are not instantiated in the moment of invoking `dojo.connect` → wrap your code into [`dojo/ready`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/ready.html)
- connecting to method which does not exist → connect to *onClick* instead of *onclick*

Based on the discussion, here is the way how to write the code in the question in [Modern Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/modern_dojo/):

```
require([
    "dojo/ready",
    "dojo/aspect",
    "dijit/registry",
    "dijit/form/Button"
], function(
    ready,
    aspect,
    registry
) {

    ready(function() {

        // dojo/Evented
        registry.byId("btnMoveFirst").on("click", function() {
            console.log("first");        
        });

        // dojo/aspect 
        // it's the same as dojo.connect in previous versions
        // nevertheless this is not recommended
        aspect.after(registry.byId("btnMoveLast"), "onClick", function() {
            console.log("last");            
        });       

    });

});
```

The working example: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/355MT/
    ​